# Hadoop Mapreduce error NativeMethodAccessor

Tags: java, hadoop

Team,

I am new to Java and trying to run a Hadoop MapReduce program. Encountered an error and unable to debug.

**Program:**

```
import java.util.*; 

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*; 

public class ProcessUnits 
{ 
   //Mapper class 
   public static class E_EMapper extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Mapper<LongWritable ,/*Input key Type */ 
   Text,                /*Input value Type*/ 
   Text,                /*Output key Type*/ 
   IntWritable>        /*Output value Type*/ 
   { 

      //Map function 
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,   
      Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
      { 
         String line = value.toString(); 
         String lasttoken = null; 
         StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
         String year = s.nextToken(); 

         while(s.hasMoreTokens())
            {
               lasttoken=s.nextToken();
            } 

         int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
         output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice)); 
      } 
   } 


   //Reducer class 
   public static class E_EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
   {  

      //Reduce function 
      public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
         OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
         { 
            int maxavg=30; 
            int val=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

            while (values.hasNext()) 
            { 
               if((val=values.next().get())>maxavg) 
               { 
                  output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val)); 
               } 
            } 

         } 
   }  


   //Main function 
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
   { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProcessUnits.class); 

      conf.setJobName("max_eletricityunits"); 
      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
      conf.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class); 
      conf.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 

      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])); 

      JobClient.runJob(conf); 
   } 
}
```

**Error:**

> Diagnostics: null Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
>   16/11/08 19:03:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0 Exception in thread
>   "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
>           at ProcessUnits.main(ProcessUnits.java:84)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Note : I am running in Windows command line.

Comment: how are you running this job?

Comment: %HADOOP_HOME%/bin/hadoop jar units.jar ProcessUnits /home/input /home/output

even tried with below command also

C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\hadoop.cmd jar units.jar ProcessUnits /home/input /home/output

But both returned the same....

Comment: is the i/o local path?

Comment: No both the paths are available in hadoop filesystem....

Comment: which hadoop version are you using?

Comment: @NirmalRam hadoop-2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

1) In the code you gave `StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t");`

check you input file in `/home/input` the given integers are separated by tab

2) In the code, replace `int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken);` 
with `int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken.trim());`

hope this works

Comment: print the output of hadoop fs -ls /home/input

Comment: because just now i tried your code with following changes. it worked fine

$ hadoop fs -ls /home/output
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs          0 2016-11-08 14:59 /home/output/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs         16 2016-11-08 14:59 /home/output/part-00000
[haas@ip-10-186-171-205 ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /home/output/part-00000
1979 40
1980 58
[haas@ip-10-186-171-205 ~]$

Comment: %HADOOP_HOME%/bin/hadoop fs -cat /home/input/sample.txt
1979    25
1980    29
1981    34
1984    40
1985    45

Comment: do you have any other file in  /home/input path?

Comment: After changing the code, did you do clean the repository

Comment: Below is what i did.

- Did code change.
- Recompiled
- Created a fresh units.jar
- And executed the Map Reduce command...

Is it some issue with my Hadoop?

Comment: How did you separate the data in input path with tab

Comment: I have manually edited the file in my local and copied back to Hadoop FS...